Change style of single word
I’ve merged a CSV list containing a column with botanical species names for a species catalog. The species names need to be displayed in bold italics, for example, Ginkgo biloba.
In some cases, the list includes species names with additional identifiers for subspecies (subsp.) or variety (var.), such as Ginkgo biloba var. triloba. However, I’m encountering an issue: the "var." is also displayed in bold italics, but it should be in regular text. Meanwhile, the final word, triloba, should still appear in bold italics.
How can I configure InDesign to display the "var." in regular text while keeping the rest of the formatting correct, without requiring too much manual effort?
Greetings Rob

I can think of 2 solutions.
1) Separate the data in Excel using Delimiters and apply character styles. How you separate might depend on how the data looks.

2) Export the data as you have been, then going back to do a find/change in InDesign. Type "var." in the Find what: box and choose the character style in the Change Format: box. This will select all words and change the character style to what you choose.


Create the paragraph style with Bold formatting, a character style with Regular formatting, and in the paragraph style add a GREP style/rule to detect var\. and use the Regular character style on it.
